# Attach Browser Event in sapui5 not working properly

Tags: sapui5

I am using focus out event type in attach Browser event for panel tool,its working properly when I click outside the panel but its even get triggered when I click inside panel.

I want that it should not trigger when i click inside panel, is it possible? if yes then how? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your code, to see how you have?

Anyway, you should check if the event was in some place which is diferent from your Panel...